# EF Core Reflect interface properties and ignore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to ignore by Fluent API specific Interface property, example:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string IgnoreThat { get; set; }
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string PropABC { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThat { get; set; } = "My Info";
}

public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public string PropEFG { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThat { get; set; } = "My Info2";
}

public class Test3 : ITest
{
    public string PropExample { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreThat { get; set; } = "My Info3";
}
```

It's very easy if in each class i add DataAnnotation **[NotMapped]**, like this:

```
public class Example: ITest
{
    public string PropExample { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string IgnoreThat { get; set; } = "My Info3";
}
```

But i have 800 classes, and i want to do this in loop, so, i start this code, but i don't know how continue:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var props = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p=>p.Name == "IgnoreThat")
                .ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            //How ignore the Property?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ModelBuilder.Entity(Type entityType)` method to get the `EntityTypeBuilder` instance and then use its `Ignore(string propertyName)` method:

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(prop.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType).Ignore(prop.Name);
}
```